# Can I use PWM with hardware audio input?

Tags: audio, pwm

I know that i cannot use pwm and audio output at the same time, can I use the audio input? I want to move some servos based on an audio trigger signal.

Comment: What do you mean by audio input?  I'm ignorant in this area but was not aware of any audio input support being provided by the hardware PWM peripheral.

Comment: never mind, i thought the pi had a 4 pole jack, so it had a microphone input.

Comment: You can use a USB dongle for audio.  Also note that there are plenty of ways of providing servo suitable PWM on the Pi without using the hardware PWM peripheral.

Answer (score 1):

There is no audio input on the Pi. You can use a GPIO header sound card ([check here for an incomplete short list](https://elinux.org/RPi_Expansion_Boards#Sound)) for audio input. It is likely that you will not be able to use the PWM onboard if you use the I2S bus for the external audio input.

Comment: You could also use a run-of-the mill USB sound adapter with a mic jack.  *Most* of them should be fine, feel free to ask if you are unsure (but please don't ask "Which one should I buy?", read "Asking for specific purchasing recommendations" on the [off-topic page](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first).